# C - "Invalid Conversion from "int*" to "int"

Tags: c, algorithm

I am new to coding. I was trying to make a program with multiple functions with different functions for Linear Search and Bubble Sort. I am using DevC++ IDE with the TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit compiler. I don't know where I made the mistake.
At line numbers 17 and 19, it shows the error "Invalid Conversion from "int*" to "int".

```
#include<stdio.h>
void LinearSearch(int,int);
void BubbleSort(int,int);
int main()
{
    int i,a[10],n;
    int size=10;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter a number\n");
        scanf("%d",&a);
    }
    printf("Press the button og=f your choice!\n");
    printf("1. Linear Seach    2. Bubble Sort\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if(n==1)
    LinearSearch(a,size); //Invalid Conversion from "int*" to "int
    else if(n==2)
    BubbleSort(a,size);  //Invalid Conversion from "int*" to "int
    else
    printf("You have pressed the wrong button!\n");
}
void LinearSearch(int a[10],int sizA)
{
    int i,s,f=0;
    printf("Enter the search value\n");
    scanf("%d",&s);
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(s==a[i])
        {
            f=1;
            printf("The Search Avlue is located at position no. %d in the array",i);
        }
    }
    if(f==0)
    printf("Search Value Not Found");
}
void BubbleSort(int a[10],int sizB)
{
    int i,j,k;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<10-i-1;j++)
        {
            if(a[j]>a[j+1])
            k=a[j];
            a[j]=a[j+1];
            a[j+1]=k;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("%d  ",a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d",&a);` -->         `scanf("%d",&a[i]);`

Comment: `&a[i]` → `a + i` ;)

Comment: @greybeard, yes, the two expressions are equivalent. However, I prefer the  `&a[i]` because it better describes what we want to do: increment the index of an array and point to the correspondent variable. That is the same of adding X Bytes to the pointer of the array where X is the `sizeof(data_type)`. I just think is less intuitive. A little bit harder to remember :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf("%d",&a)` should be `scanf("%d",&a[i])`

and also correct your function forward declarations from

```
void LinearSearch(int,int);
void BubbleSort(int,int);
```

to

```
void LinearSearch(int[],int);
void BubbleSort(int[],int);
```

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of your two function does not match with the definition. To be clear, you have declared:

```
void LinearSearch(int,int);  //<---the two arguments are int
void BubbleSort(int,int);    //<---the two arguments are int
```

But, in the end, you define your function as:

```
void LinearSearch(int a[10],int sizA); //<---the first argument is an int*
void BubbleSort(int a[10],int sizB);   //<---the first argument is an int*
```

If you want to solve the compilation error you are reporting, please just substitute your declarations with this two line!

**P.S.** Please also note that there are other little problems you may want to solve (when using `scanf("%d",&a);`). As point out in one of the comment, the correct instruction should be `scanf("%d",&a[i]);`.